# Google Sheets: Query Function - Counting unique values, but failing to show zeros

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a function that allows me to count how many times a column has a certain phrase (i used dropdown menus in the column) and then sorting it by the month. However, if there is a month that doesn't have any of the items I am searching it doesn't populate a row in the query table showing that month had zero of the burgers, etc. Does anyone know how to have the query function show the 0 for months that did not have results.

=QUERY('2022'!A1:Z,
"select count(E)
where E= 'Burgers' and B >=date """&text(D2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&""" and B<=date """&text(D3,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"""
group by B
Label count(E) 'Burgers'")

Comment: Something like `=QUERY(IF('2022'!A1:Z="",0,'2022'!A1:Z).......` Share a sample workbook.

Comment: Sorry! Heres a link of a sample sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mu4eaI-sZ-rb6h0kwohAS99ZKiDml7FjEKNpKs9R_C0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula in a single cell.

```
={INDEX(TEXT(DATE(YEAR(D3),SEQUENCE(MONTH(D3)-MONTH(D2)+1),1),"mmmm yyyy")),
INDEX(MAP(DATE(YEAR(D3),SEQUENCE(MONTH(D3)-MONTH(D2)+1),1),LAMBDA(x,COUNTIFS(Data!D2:D,"Burgers",Data!A2:A,">="&x,Data!A2:A,"<="&EOMONTH(x,0))))),
INDEX(MAP(DATE(YEAR(D3),SEQUENCE(MONTH(D3)-MONTH(D2)+1),1),LAMBDA(x,COUNTIFS(Data!D2:D,"Drinks",Data!A2:A,">="&x,Data!A2:A,"<="&EOMONTH(x,0)))))}
```

[image]

Comment: Sheet link [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DPGmYvtx4oVC30MOk9fq2CEJemEtFX5OJFeLUi7FjSU/edit?usp=sharing).